# My python rock paper scissors app ends without printing anything?

Tags: python

I have made a RPS app but it exits after user provides input. It ends without an error.

CODE:

```
def game(USER, COMPUTER):
#GO THROUGH OBVIOUS RESULTS FIRST
if USER == "ROCK" and COMPUTER == "ROCK":
    print("It's a draw.\nI picked", COMPUTER)
if USER == "PAPER" and COMPUTER == "PAPER":
    print("It's a draw.\nI picked", COMPUTER)
if USER == "SCISSORS" and COMPUTER == "SCISSORS":
    print("It's a draw.\nI picked", COMPUTER)

#USER PICKS PAPER
if USER == "PAPER" and COMPUTER == "ROCK":
    print("YES! I WIN!!!!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Oh, wait. No I didn't. You won.\nI chose", COMPUTER)
if USER == "PAPER" and COMPUTER == "SCISSORS":
    print("YEOOOO! I WON! I picked", COMPUTER)

#USER PICKS ROCK
if USER == "ROCK" and COMPUTER == "PAPER":
    print("HA! NO WAY! I WON! I picked", COMPUTER)
if USER == "ROCK" and COMPUTER == "SCISSORS":
    print("Awwwww. You broke me... \nI picked", COMPUTER)

#USER PICKS SICSSORS
if USER == "SICSSORS" and COMPUTER == "ROCK":
    print("*YOU WERE SMASHED INTO THE SHAPE OF AN L. FOR LOSER.*\nI picked", COMPUTER)
if USER == "SICSSORS" and COMPUTER == "PAPER":
    print("*SNIP SNIP SNIP*")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("*IS THROWN IN BIN*")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("*WISPERS FROM BIN* Hey, that means you won...\nI picked", COMPUTER)


print("ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!")

time.sleep(1)
print("Ready?")
time.sleep(1)

#get user input
USER=str(input("\nWHAT WILL YOU CHOSE!\nROCK,\nPAPER\nor SCISSORS?\nINPUT YOUR ANSWER NOW: "))

#RANDOM WEAPON GENRATION!
COMPUTER=random.randint(1 ,3)

if COMPUTER == 1:
    COMPUTER = "ROCK"
elif COMPUTER == 2:
    COMPUTER = "PAPER"
elif COMPUTER == 3:
    COMPUTER = "SCISSORS"

print("\nGENERATING RESULT. PLEASE WAIT...\n")

#Validating response
USER.upper()

game(USER, COMPUTER)
```

This generates this output:

```
ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!
Ready?

WHAT WILL YOU CHOSE!
ROCK,
PAPER
or SCISSORS?
INPUT YOUR ANSWER NOW: rock

GENERATING RESULT. PLEASE WAIT...
```

and then ends there.

I apologize for the long code, but i don't know if you can recreate this without this code

PS: I want it to print the result based on the variables

EG

```
USER = PAPER 
COMPUTER = ROCK
```

the printed result should be:

```
YES! I WIN!
Oh, wait. No I didn't. You won
I picked ROCK
```

Comment: It doesn't appear your function is properly indented? Is this an issue with copying and pasting your code or an issue in your actual source?

Comment: @NathanielFord, please don't fix indentation on Python questions.

Comment: @MorganThrapp The indentation is not the issue here: The indentation intended is pretty obvious, and would not create the issue being caused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `upper` method doesn't alter the original object (remember, strings are immutable in Python). Instead, it returns a copy with all capital letters. So it should be:

```
USER = USER.upper()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is this line:

```
USER.upper()
```

The `upper()` method returns a **copy** of the string which is converted to uppercase. It doesn't modify the original. You probably want to try this instead:

```
USER = USER.upper()
```

As a side note, the program isn't actually exiting early. It looks like it is calling the `game()` function as intended. It's just that none of the `if` conditions evaluates to True, so no visible actions are carried out. You could implement it as a series of `if...elif...elif...` instead of disparate `if` conditions. At the very end, put an `else` which could output an error message to say that the input wasn't recognised.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious things which may be causing problems:

```
USER.upper()
```

should be

```
USER = USER.upper()
```

Secondly, you are making this comparison:

```
if USER == "SICSSORS" and COMPUTER == "ROCK":
```

Where `SICSSORS` must be the wrong spelling, and thus you are likely to skip this branch of logic.